# Cannot see a Material list-grid item inside a child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I'm newbie in Angular7.
I am writing an app with Material. 
I am trying to write a material grid list dinamically in two components: list and item. Like this:

Component-list:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <app-concept-item
    *ngFor="let conceptItem of conceptList"
    (click)="goToConceptDetail(concept.id)"
    [concept]="conceptItem">
    </app-concept-item>
</mat-grid-list>
```

And the Item component inside (app-concept-item):

```
<mat-grid-tile>
    <span>{{concept.name}}</span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
```

When I run the code, in the Chrome Inspect tool, the HTML is correctly writed in the view. But I can't see anything, I see a blank page.

In the other hand, if I don't split the code into another component, it is performed totally correct:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let concept of conceptList"
    (click)="goToConceptDetail(concept.id)">
        <span>{{concept.name}}</span>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

The result with the second code is:

[image]

I don't have any css code in any of the solutions. 
The first one shows nothing, the second one, what you see in the picture.

Any help appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: I think `mat-grid-list` just needs to have `mat-grid-tiles` as direct children. There is nothing you can do about it. You should put your `app-concept-item` inside a `mat-grid-tile` and not the other way around.

Comment: thanks @fridoo . I was wondering if this should be that way, and I can't split it in components. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: its pretty inconsistent, considering that with angular mat list <mat-list-item> it does work even if you put the <mat-list-item> into a child component..